# what is the integral of $(e^v)/(W(v)+1) dv$

Tags: integration, special-functions, lambert-w

I got this from working on the integral of
$$x^x dx$$
and with
$$u=x^x \Rightarrow du=x^x\cdot \ln(ex)$$
I got the integral of
$$\frac{u}{(x^x\cdot \ln(ex))}du$$
which becomes
$$\frac{1}{\ln(ex)} du$$
which using the fact that
$$x=e^{W(\ln(u))}$$
(when x is real and greater than one)

I got
$$\frac{1}{\ln(e^{W(\ln(u)+1})} du$$
which simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{W(\ln(u))+1} du$$
which using
$$v=\ln(u) \Rightarrow dv=\frac{1}{u} du$$
or
$$dv\cdot u=du$$
or
$$dv\cdot e^v=du$$
so then I got
$$\frac{1}{W(v)+1}\cdot e^v dv$$
so that is how I got the integral of
$$\frac{e^v}{W(v)+1}dv $$

note: $W(z)$ is the Lambert W function of z
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

If you find a mistake in one of my steps please put it in the comments and I will fix it as soon as I can

So, my final question is: **What is the integral of** $$\frac{e^v}{W(v)+1}dv $$

Note: in case it’s useful, according to Wolfram Alpha the integral of $\frac{1}{W(v)+1}$ is $\frac{v}{W(v)}$

Comment: If $u = x^x$ then $du = x^x ( 1 + \log(x))dx$.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin yes but 1+ln(x) = ln(e)+ln(x) = ln(ex) so du=x^x*ln(ex)

Comment: is it $e^{\frac{v}{W(v)+1}}$ or $\frac{e^{v}}{W(v)+1}$ ?

Comment: Your work is correct but if we were able to integrate it, then no more *Somophore dream*.

Comment: @LinconRibeiro it is the second one, (e^v)/(W(v)+1)

Comment: I've edited your question. Please check if it still reflects your thoughts.

Comment: what is $ln(ex)$ supposed to be? Is it $1+\ln x$?